# ld: cannot find -lX11 or -lpng

Tags: linux, npm, ld

Running `npm install face-recognition` runs fine on my mac, but when I try to do it on my Debian VM, it fails with the following error:

```
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/facerec.node
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
facerec.target.mk:157: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/facerec.node' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/facerec.node] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/ben/face-rec/node_modules/face-recognition/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ben/face-rec/node_modules/face-recognition
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN face-rec@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! face-recognition@0.9.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the face-recognition@0.9.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ben/.npm/_logs/2018-07-15T19_28_00_238Z-debug.log
```

I think the key parts are lines 2 and 3, the parts about `ld` not being able to find `-lX11` or `-lpng`. This is easily solved on a mac by installing Xquartz, but a workaround seems impossible on a Linux server. Any ideas?

Comment: How is the problem related with CMake, which you use as a tag? Do not confuse it with `make`.

Comment: When I was originally writing the question I tagged it with cmake because of its presence in the error message, but then realized it was irrelevant. Deleted.

Comment: Are those libraries installed?

Comment: That’s my question, I do not know how to install them.

Comment: [`libx11-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libx11-dev) can be installed using Apt to satisfy the first requirement. Likewise, `libpng-dev` (and if necessary, `libpng++-dev`) will satisfy the second requirement.

Comment: Put that in an actual answer and I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're simply missing the libraries. Try this:

```
apt-get install libpng-dev libx11
```